# Как добавить классы к таблице по клику с помощью localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, возможно это простая задача, но я никак не могу ее решить.
Есть таблица, как добавить классы в каждый тег 'td' по клику и сохранить в хранилище с помощью localstorage? Просто добавить классы по клику я смог, но после перезагрузки классы все равно не сохраняются.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('body').on('click', 'td', function(event){

  var go = $(this);

  localStorage.setItem('set', go);

  go.attr('class', 'marker_new');  

  localStorage.setItem('sum', 'marker_new');

});
var color = localStorage.getItem('set');
var color1 = localStorage.getItem('sum');
$(color).attr('class', color1);

});
```

Comment: Вам надо сохранять в `localStorage` не сам эелемент `go`, а его уникальный путь или идентификатор.

Comment: Но ведь если я сохраню идентификатор, то классы добавятся ко всем элементам 'td' , разве нет?

Comment: вам же сказали _уникальный_ путь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD:**

Тогда вот так:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('td').on('click', function(){

   var go = String(this.parentNode.rowIndex)+String(this.cellIndex);

   localStorage.setItem('set'+go, go); //в localStorage заносим ключ в виде "set + уникальный индекс ячейки" и значение в виде "уникальный индекс ячейки"

   $(this).addClass('marker_new');

 });
 
 $('td').each(function(i){ //в цикле проверяем, совпадает ли индекс ячейки со значением из localStorage
  if(String(this.parentNode.rowIndex)+String(this.cellIndex) == localStorage.getItem('set'+String(this.parentNode.rowIndex)+String(this.cellIndex))) {
   $(this).addClass('marker_new');
  }
 });

});
```

```css
td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.marker_new {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

---

---

Всё-таки не очень понятно, какой именно результат Вы хотите получить. У Вас в локальном хранилище только два параметра (set и sum), которые при каждом клике заново перезаписываются.

(*Причём класс marker_new вообще всегда один и тот же - зачем его каждый раз заносить в локальное хранилище и каждый раз получать обратно? Непонятно*).

После перезагрузки страницы результат в любом случае сохранится только для последней ячейки, по которой был совершён клик.

Если же так и задумано, то вот рабочий вариант (***здесь localStorage не воспроизводится - скопируйте себе на локальную страницу***):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('td').on('click', function(){ //при клике на ячейку...
  
          $(this).attr('class', 'marker_new'); //добавляем ей класс

   var go = String(this.parentNode.rowIndex)+String(this.cellIndex); //... записываем в переменную уникальный индекс ячейки (номер строки + номер самой ячейки)

   localStorage.setItem('set', go); //заносим индекс в локальное хранилище

   localStorage.setItem('sum', 'marker_new'); //заносим класс в локальное хранилище

 });
 
 var color = localStorage.getItem('set'); //получаем индекс
 
 var color1 = localStorage.getItem('sum'); //получаем класс
 
 $('td').each(function(){ //в цикле пробегаем по всем ячейкам и ищем совпадение с индексом из локального хранилища
  if(String(this.parentNode.rowIndex)+String(this.cellIndex) == color) {
   $(this).addClass(color1); //добавляем класс этой ячейке
  }
 });

});
```

```css
td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.marker_new {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Этот код сохраняет последний клик я это уже реализовал , мне нужно чтобы он запомнил все клики которые были нажаты по ячейкам и сохранил их после перезагрузки страницы. То есть кликаю по двум ячейкам, они загорелись красным и оставались такими же красными и после перезагрузки страницы

Comment: @SaulGoodman, я обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)